# Ill-formed XML document (missing opening tag for hierarchy). Try changing the 'normalizeTagNames' driver setting to 'true' in Appium

Tags: appium-android

When I execute my mobile automation suite using single thread, its running fine however if I run the same suite using multiple thread I am getting below error

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error in building: Ill-formed XML document (missing opening tag for hierarchy). Try changing the 'normalizeTagNames' driver setting to 'true' in order to workaround the problem.`

I explored the solution in google and found that normalizeTagNames should be set to true however dont know where / how to set it

Please help on this